# translate an actionscript2 into an actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, actionscript-2, flash-cc

i'd like to convert this actionscript 2 instruction:

```
button_btn.onRelease = function():Void
{
   getURL('javascript:shrinkSkinOverlayDiv()');
}
```

to an actionscript 3 one.At the moment i'm using adobe flash-cc which doesn't support actionscript 2 actions anymore. Since i'm really noob with flash, i need some help (accepted a work from my boss which i can't even accomplish :P).

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html#articlecontentAdobe_codeblock_22).

Comment: this should be the convertion:

    this.btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, function()
    {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://flash.html.it"),"_blank");
    });

but how do i write the 'javascript:shrinkSkinOverlayDiv()' part in it?

Comment: Take a look on [`navigateToURL()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()) ... For your case, `javascript:shrinkSkinOverlayDiv()` is your URL, so you can do : `navigateToURL(new URLRequest('javascript:shrinkSkinOverlayDiv()'), '_self');`.

Answer (score 1):

For your button, use [`addEventListener()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()) to listen for [`MouseEvent.CLICK`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#CLICK) events.

To call a JavaScript function, use [`ExternalInterface.call()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call()).

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

button_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:Event):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("shrinkSkinOverlayDiv");
}
```